# How to make the user enter the value of the same variable again?

Tags: java

I'm new to the programming and I was making a simple absence program but I'm stuck with if someone enters a value that is neither A for absent or T for attended. Here is the code:

```
package loops;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Students_Absence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter T for the attended student and A for the absent");
        System.out.print("Student1:");
        char student1 = input.next().charAt(0);

        if (student1 =='T' || student1 == 'A'){
             System.out.println();
        }   else {
            System.out.println("The sympol you entered is incorrect, please use either T or A");
            char student1 = input.next().charAt(0);
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

I want the user to enter the value again if he miss-clicks or something rather then restarting the whole program. But I get the (duplicate local variable) error when I try to.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to redeclare the variable, just re-assign to it (in the marked line):

```
student1 = input.next().charAt(0);
```

Anyway, you should probably implement it as a loop, since the user may enter a wrong value again...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be declaring `student1` twice, once before the if statement and another time in the else. Consider reusing `student1` variable in the else block.

```
else {
    System.out.println("The sympol you entered is incorrect, please use either T or A");
    student1 = input.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `char` type again in your `else` block:

```
System.out.println("The sympol you entered is incorrect, please use either T or A");
student1 = input.next().charAt(0);
```

The error comes because you are trying to create the same variable two times (when you use `char` before a name of a variable you are creating a new variable) and you just have to assing its value again (using the name of the variable but without the keyword `char`), not to re-create it.